# `docker compose up` what is flags difference`--always-recreate-deps` vs `--build`

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-image

`--always-recreate-deps` is described as:

> Recreate dependent containers. Incompatible with --no-recreate.

`--build` is described as:

> Build images before starting containers.

What is the difference between "Recreate dependent containers" and "Build images before starting containers"?

When a Dockerfile changed I use `docker compose up --build`. Do I need to also use `--always-recreate-deps`?

What are use cases for the `--always-recreate-deps` while we already have `--build` and `--force-recreate`?

Answer (score 0):

`--always-recreate-deps:` This option tells Docker Compose to always recreate the dependencies of a service, even if they haven't changed. This means that if a service depends on another service, and the other service's image hasn't been updated, Docker Compose will still recreate that service when the up command is run with the --always-recreate-deps option.

`--build:` This option tells Docker Compose to build the images for all services defined in the docker-compose.yml file before starting the containers. This is useful if you have made changes to your services and want to ensure that the images are rebuilt and the containers are running the latest version of your code.

In summary, --always-recreate-deps option ensures that all dependent services are recreated even if they haven't changed whereas --build option ensures that the images are rebuilt and the containers are running the latest version of your code.